# Google Cloud Functions can't make "import io"

Tags: python, google-cloud-functions

I try to launch Google Cloud Function.
io lib is used:

```
from io import BytesIO
```

But when I try to add 'io' to requirements.txt function deploy with error.
The mistake happen only when I add this string to the file.

How I can fix it?

Comment: What error do you get? Search for that error online to get an idea what's going on.

Comment: are you following any guide? this may be a case of Google Cloud being deprecated in some libraries

Comment: There is no exact error. Noisy deploy was failed and string “io” deleted. 

I haven’t find any mention about this library in google docs. Yes. Maybe it just deprecated and I should use Google App Engine for it